# Do the regions in Soul Eater match perfectly to the real world?

Tags: soul-eater

The Death Sycthes' manage real world regions as like a replacement to Death's Eight Guardians, they are.

- Spirit Albarn - North America
- Marie Mjolnir - Oceania
- Azusa Yumi - Eastern Asia
- Justin Law - Western Europe
- Tezca Tlipoca - South America
- Tsar Pushka - Eastern Europe
- Deng Dinga and Djinn Galland - Africa and Western Asia (How Wikipedia list them, not sure which is which)

I am wondering if these region are the same as the regions in our world? if so would that make Death City be located in North America?

Comment: Do you remember in which episode they show the map?

Comment: @user1306322 i don't think they ever do, i'm just using logic, if Spirit manages North America and is always in Death City would that make Death City in North America but that's assuming that North America is the same North America we have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is related to the real world. There's no map ever shown, but Death City is a fictional city set in Nevada, USA.

> Shibusen is an academy located in the fictional Death City, of Nevada where Meisters and Weapons attend.

Source: [Soul Eater wiki: Shibusen](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Shibusen)

Also, it's not listed, but I'm quite sure (judging by appearance) that Deng Dinga is from Africa, and Djinn Galland is from Western Asia.